# How can I store the result of my python script into a new csv file?

Tags: python, bash, csv

Basically I have a bash script that wget's the html of a page, convert it to xhtml using tagsoup and then extracts elements via the python script. Nothing seems to work, I just need the output of that python script to be stored in a new $d csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 10s
do

d=`date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`;

wget -O $d.html http://wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-activnyse-actives.html

java -jar tagsoup-1.2.1.jar --files $d.html

python3 idk.py $d.xhtml

done
~
```

Comment: what's the content of `idk.py`? or is that the file you don't know how to write?

Comment: `python3 idk.py "$d.html" > "$d.csv"`

Comment: that file is fine, and it prints out my extracted list when i run it. just want to output the result into a new csv file as opposed to just on the terminal when i run it

Comment: @yinnonsanders that did the trick. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have just to use that command line :

```
python3 idk.py > $d.xhtml
```